# How can ı write test for logging with spring aop?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, spring-aop

I searched but ı couldnt find and understand how ı can write a test for my code

AOP

```
    @Slf4j
    @Aspect
    @Component
    public class SpringAopLogging {

    @Pointcut("execution(public* *(..)) && @within(com.muaz.aop.Logger)")
    public void isAnnotated() {}

    @Before("isAnnotated()")
    public void before(JoinPoint point) {
            log.info(" parameters : {} ", point.getArgs());
    }

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "isAnnotated()", returning = "retVal")
    public void after(JoinPoint point, Object retVal) {
        log.info("retVal is : {}", retVal);
    }
}
```

Annotation

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Logger {
}
```

Service

```
@Service
@Logger
public class StudentService {

public Student updateStudentName(Student student, String name){
  student.setName(name);
  return student;
     }
}
```

ı want to test @Before and @AfterReturning can work with @Logger at method execution

Comment: Testing any method without a return type/arguments/exceptions are not easy. I don't think such methods qualify for unit-tests.

Comment: A probable way might be log to a file and tail the file for expected log messages after method is called.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need here is an integration test to test the effect of the AOP configuration.
You don't test the AOP config since it won't make any sense you bearly has one line of code there.

Instead, you need to test if for example the following line `parameters : {new Student(),"john"}` is logged when you inject `StudentService` and call e.g `updateStudentName(new Student(), "john")`